# Is there a bzr command to see all branches of a project on Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

If you visit a project on Launchpad, you can see all active branches of all developers involved in the project.

Is there a `bzr` command to do the same without visiting the project's page on Launchpad in a browser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of any `bzr` command that does this, but it's actually very easy to script using the [Launchpad python API](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib). For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad

cachedir = os.path.expanduser("~/.launchpadlib/cache/")
launchpad = Launchpad.login_anonymously('find_branches',
                                        'production',
                                        cachedir)

try:
    project = launchpad.projects[sys.argv[1]]
    for b in project.getBranches():
        if b.lifecycle_status not in ["Abandoned", "Merged"]:
            print b.bzr_identity
except KeyError:
    print "Project unknown... \nUsage: " + sys.argv[0] + " lp_project_name"
```

So with `python find_branches.py deluge` we get:

```
lp:deluge
lp:~vcs-imports/deluge/trunk
lp:~mvoncken/deluge/ajax-template-dev
lp:~deluge-team/deluge/master
lp:~shaohao/deluge/0.9
lp:~damoxc/deluge/master
```

You can run wild with it and do things like sort by `date_created`, `date_last_modified`, or create your own heuristic for what branches are interesting to you. See:

https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/1.0.html#branch

Answer (score 4):

[Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) is a version control system no more then that, completely separate project from [Launchpad](https://dev.launchpad.net/).

It is possible to parse directly the project branches HTML page or its Atom news feed.

1. Declare a shell function:

   ```
   lslp() {
       wget -q -O - http://feeds.launchpad.net/$1/branches.atom | xml2 | grep "/feed/entry/title=" | cut -c 19-;
   }
   ```

   - `wget -q -O - http://feeds.launchpad.net/projectname/branches.atom`

     get branches news feed (Atom xml)
   - `xml2`

     convert XML document to a flat format
   - `grep "/feed/entry/title="`

     filter out lines with "/feed/entry/title=", XML nodes that contain branch name
   - `cut -c 19-`

     remove "/feed/entry/title=" from result lines.
2. Example:

   ```
   $ lslp deluge
   lp:deluge
   lp:~vcs-imports/deluge/trunk
   lp:~damoxc/deluge/master
   lp:~deluge-team/deluge/master
   lp:~shaohao/deluge/0.9
   lp:~mvoncken/deluge/ajax-template-dev
   ```